# A* with enemy awareness

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I'm currently dabbling in Java AI programming, and trying an AI challenge. In the challenge, my AI is given 2 seconds to respond to the new game state. If these two seconds are exceeded without producing a response, my AI forfeits. The game consists of a grid with goals and enemies, each enemy being an independent AI generated by the game. I have implemented a standard A* to find the nearest available goal.

I would like my A* algorithm to increase the cost of squares near an enemy that could potentially prove dangerous, thus avoiding dangerous paths. I am considering a two-dimensional array containing the estimated loss of health for each square, limited to calculating within ~2 squares of each enemy (~5x5). Each turn, for each enemy this array would have a 5x5 square set to 0 and recalculated.

Assuming I write code that only does what it must and moves on... Will a two dimensional array of between 20x20 and 100x100 elements significantly effect execution time? Is a two dimensional array of estimated threat per square a good method of calculating cost in an A* algorithm so as to avoid enemies?

UPDATE:
I got it working absolutely perfectly. The cost function I used:

```
For each enemy
    Calculate manhattan distance
    If 0 or 1, cost += absolute(enemy health - health) / 5
    Else if 2, cost += absolute(enemy heath - health) / 10
    Else cost += 0
```

Using it, I saw some really impressive pathfinding and moves; the bot would often take calculated risks where there were no other moves to get to a goal, but basically avoided enemies otherwise. I was thoroughly impressed with how insignificant the performance cost was of adding the heuristic. It's not a perfect solution for the game, but it showed me how robust A* can be.

A* is generally used for pathfinding, but I'm going to modify it for the purpose of a game state lookahead. I'm pretty sure that turns it into a minimax algorithm.

Comment: Have you tried running a profiler on your code, to see where the bottlenecks are?

Comment: @Robert Harvey No. I am currently executing in about 0.1-0.5 seconds per AI (I may run multiple AI threaded) according to System.nanoTime(). I'm speculating on how I might improve the behaviour without greatly increasing this amount of time. user2864740: Yes, they get a move every turn as well.

Comment: Without seeing your code, I'm not sure how much we can help you.  A profiler would be better advice; it will tell you where the hot spots are.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I just ran the code and checked the output and it seems I misconverted nanoseconds. It takes between 0.00001 and 0.2 seconds to run, with a normal execution time of about 0.001 seconds. There aren't significant bottlenecks; yet. I'm concerned if the method I imagine of avoiding enemies is going to have a significant impact on time. I'm currently trying to avoid solutions which exceed my time budget, not to optimize pre-existing code that executes well within my time constraints.

Comment: We don't have a crystal ball.  There are at least a dozen things that I can think of that could affect the performance of your code having nothing to do with its design, and you're focusing on the design without showing us some code as a baseline.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm designing and execution time is one factor to consider. Will a two dimensional array of estimated threat encourage A* to find a path around enemies? Will changing 25 integer values twice every turn per enemy take a significant amount of time? That is the essence of my question.

Comment: Those are the kinds of questions that are best asked of a profiler or some simple timing code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey 'Write code, test, and don't waste my time' is what you mean to say? Now I see why you imagined I asked for clairvoyance. I was asking foresight, the kind of wisdom that comes from having experience. I suppose the issue is that I wasted this time looking for an answer both here and online when I could have been coding. We both are right, but your perspective is a bit more realistic, if a bit unpalatable (I avoid trial and error).

Comment: Not to put too fine a point on this, but what is "trial and error" about putting 10000 integers into an array, starting a timer, changing all of the values, and examining the time elapsed? How long would it take you to do that?  I suppose I could fire up an editor, write some code and answer it for you, but... y'know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only calculating the content of your array once and the calculation
for each cell is something simple like checking a few adjacent cells for enemies then
a 100x100 array is no work at all relative to your time constraints.

Given the information in your post it sounds like a good idea to me.